# IIS - Deploy ASP.NET MVC in custom domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I need to deploy my ASP.NET MVC APP on IIS, everythink work fine, but my client will not use root domain like: `http://127.0.0.1:6604` but custom domain like: `http://intranet/apply`. I know that in PHP is APACHE Server is possible use htaccess file and set RewriteBase. Is somethink similiar possible in .NET and how ?

Edit:

Web page wroks, is loaded correctly, but all request targets is without: /apply extensions.

SO:
http://intranet/apply is base domain
all requests on page all translated to http://intranet/ => missing apply => page need apply in URL

Thanks !

Comment: you might want to try googling first, then ask a specific question if you get stuck

Comment: Add a binding in IIS for intranet